# Find the general solution of the differential equation (separable equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the differential equation

2.$$\frac{dy}{dt}=(1+t)(1+y)$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+y}=(1+t)dt$$
$$\int \frac{1}{(1+y}=\int (1+t)dt$$
$$ln|1+y|=t+(1/2)t^2+C$$
$$e^{ln|1+y|}=e^{t+(1/2)t^2+C}$$
$$|1+y|=e^{t+(1/2)t^2+C}$$ Do I need to keep these absolute value signs?
$$|y|=e^{t+(1/2)t^2+C}-1$$

4.$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{t+y+3}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^te^ye^3$$
$$\frac{1}{e^y}dy=e^te^3dt$$
$$\int \frac{1}{e^y}dy=\int e^te^3dt$$
$$ln|e^y|=e^te^3+C$$
$$|y|=e^te^3+C$$

Does my work look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, no, it's not necessary. You could write $1 + y = Ae^{t + (1/2)t^2}$ or $y = Ae^{t + (1/2)t^2} - 1$. Your work for problem $4$ looks incorrect; the integral $\int \frac{1}{e^y} \, dy$ is $-e^{-y} + C$.